# Javascript Google Maps API3 Polygon Multiple Circles

Tags: javascript, maps

I am using Mysql and PHP to generate XML which is consumed by a Google Map. I am setting markers and polygon circles. The markers set with no problems, however only one polygon circle is displayed, not the other nine (a total of ten is returned from the database)
I am quite certain this is an array issue, however I just cant seem to put my finger on why only one polygon is created. Hopeful someone can get me pointed in the right direction, here is my code:

```
   //function to consume xml
   var xml = parseXml(data); 
   var polygonNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("polygon"); 
   for (var i = 0; i < polygonNodes.length; i++) {
   var polylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 
          parseFloat(polygonNodes[i].getAttribute("polygon_lat")), 
          parseFloat(polygonNodes[i].getAttribute("polygon_lng"))); 
   }
   createCircle(polylatlng);

  //here i am creating the polygon circle
  function createCircle(polylatlng) { 
  var html = "<div id='infodiv'>HelloWorld</div>"; 
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map,
        center: polylatlng,
        fillColor: '#7491D3',
        fillOpacity: 0.03,
        strokeColor: '#7491D3',
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        radius: 18362.55489862987
        }); 
  google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function() { 
    infoWindow.setContent(html); 
    infoWindow.open(map, circle); 
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm reading this wrong, you're not including the `createCircle` function in your loop, so it only gets called once. Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polygonNodes.length; i++) {
    var polylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 
          parseFloat(polygonNodes[i].getAttribute("polygon_lat")), 
          parseFloat(polygonNodes[i].getAttribute("polygon_lng"))
    ); 
    createCircle(polylatlng);
}
```

Good code indentation is helpful for issues like this :).

Comment: Thank you very much! Still learning etiquette of SO so thank you for your patience and kindness

Comment: No problem - if this was the right answer and your code works now, you can mark it as correct by hitting the checkmark at the top left :).